# RecyclerView with nested ViewPager2 inside BottomSheet

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet, android-viewpager2

I have RecyclerView inside BottomSheet. It has different kinds of views inside the rows (TextView, MaterialCardView and ViewPager2). This RecyclerView should not scroll vertically while BottomSheet is in the collapsed state - Bottom Sheet should expand on scrolling instead. And this behaviour works correctly when I touching any row of RecyclerView except one that contains ViewPager2.  In case of touching the cell of ViewPager2 RecyclerView just scrolls vertically and expending of BottomSheet doesn't happening.